# Is something like this even possible in CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

Is it possible to make 2 picture overlap this way ?

[image: 2 images cross sectioned]
Imagine you have 2 images both like 60% of the resulting image.  They should overlap, but by a diagonally cutout.

Comment: Thanks @Banana ! Just posted a pessimistic comment. Deleted it when I saw yours :)

Comment: transform rotate + overflow hidden + z-index

Comment: Yes. Look in to `transform:rotate` and `overflow:hidden` to get started.

Comment: Is [SVG](http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) an option?

Comment: [This](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) is exactly what you need

Comment: Why bother about SVG if others say it's possible :-D

Answer (score 11):

Either you use CSS Masking or you play around with CSS3 transform rotate:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

You would rotate one inner container by say 45 degrees and the image inside that container by -45 degrees to make it straight again. The result is a diagonal border. Add z-index and absolute positioning and you got your result.

Here's a demo.

```css
.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 50px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #666;
}
.img1 {
    border-right: 2px solid #666;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: -75px;
    top: -230px;
    z-index: 2;
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.img1 img {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.img2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 150px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="img1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-600-300-7.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="img2"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-600-300-10.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```